# Entropy of Van der Waals fluid

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Given the thermal equation of state of van der Waals gas as $$(p-an^2/V^2)(V-nb)=nRT$$ how can its entropy be calculated?

Comment: Are you saying the entropy definition is not derived from the ideal gas law?

Comment: I am not sure that we can obtain the entropy function for the van der walls fluid.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to prove. The entropy definition has nothing to do with the  equation of state for a gas.

Comment: It is possible to prove in complete generality that the entropy defined through $\Delta S = Q/T$ is a function of state. Using the ideal gas is not necessary. Sometimes it is used as an exercise. It is also possible to recover the entropy corresponding to the van der Waals equation of state. However, one should also provide the equation for the energy as a function of temperature.

Comment: GiorgioP: You can prove that the entropy is a state variable (function) by using the second law of thermodynamics. However, this is not satisfactory in my opinion. My question is how would you show that S is a state function for vdw if the equation of state is given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with $TdS=dU+pdV$, substitute $p=\frac{nRT}{V-nb}-\frac{an^2}{V^2}$, divide by $T$, you get: $$dU=TdS-\left(\frac{nRT}{V-nb}-\frac{an^2}{V^2}\right)dV$$
Let the caloric equation be $\delta Q = C_vdT$ where $C_v=C_v(T,V)$ so that
$$dU=C_vdT+T\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}-\left(\frac{nRT}{V-nb}-\frac{an^2}{V^2}\right)dV\tag{**}$$
but you also have in general that $dU=C_vdT+\left(T\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}-p\right)dV$ and because $dU$ is a perfect differential
$$\frac{\partial C_v}{\partial V}=\frac{\partial}{\partial T}\left(T\frac{\partial p}{\partial T} -p\right)=T\frac{\partial^2p}{\partial T^2}$$ But this is $0$ for the van der Waals gas, that is $\frac{\partial C_v}{\partial V}=0$, therefore $C_v=C_v(T)$ and
$$\delta Q=TdS=dU+pdV\\
C_vdT+\frac{RT}{V-nb}dV$$ or
$$dS=\frac{C_v}{T}dT+\frac{nR}{V-nb}dV$$ and
$$S-S_0=\int_{T_0}^T\frac{C_v}{T}dT+nR\int_{T_0}^T\frac{1}{V-nb}dV$$and
$$S(T,V)=S_0+\int_{T_0}^T\frac{C_v(T)}{T}dT+nR \rm{ln} \left( \frac {V-nb}{V_0-nb} \right) $$

---

** thanks to @Chemomechanics for pointing out that the 2nd term $T\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}$ was missing; it was correctly shown in the next equation as consequence of Maxwell's relation.

---

***Addendum***: A similar result can be derived for a somewhat more general thermal equation of state such as $p(T,V)=Tf(V)+g(V)$. (for the vdW fluid $f(V)=\frac{nR}{V-nb}$ and $g(V)=\frac{an^2}{V^2}$)

Let $S=S(T,V)$ then $$dU=TdS-pdV=T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}dT+\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}dV\right)-pdV\\
=T\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}dT+\left(T\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}-p \right)dV$$ Now use Maxwell's equation $\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}=\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}$ and write $C_v=T\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}$:
$$dU=C_vdT+\left(T\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}-p \right)dV$$
For this gas $\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}=f(V)$ and also $\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial T^2}=0$. Now use the equality of mixed partial derivatives for $dU$ to be exact differential, that is
$$\frac{\partial C_v}{\partial V} = \frac{\partial}{\partial T}\left(T\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}-p \right)
=\frac{\partial T}{\partial T}\frac{\partial p}{\partial T} + T \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial T^2}-\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}=0$$
Wee that $C_v=C_v(T)$ independently of $V$. We can integrate the entropy by noting that $T\frac{\partial p}{\partial T} = Tf$, therefore $dU=C_vdT+(Tf-p)dV=C_vdT-gdV$: $$dS=\frac{1}{T}dU+\frac{p}{T}dV\\
\frac{C_v}{T}dT+\frac{p-g}{T}dV=\frac{C_v}{T}dT+fdV$$
and $$S-S_0=\int_{T_0}^T \frac{C_v(T)}{T}dT + \int_{V_0}^V f(V)dV$$

Comment: Thank you for this derivation.

Comment: The caloric  equation is more complex for a van der Waals fluid, though.  The expression $dU=c_VdT+\left(T\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}-P\right)dV$ Is always true, as you note. By replacing $T\,dS$ with $c_VdT$ in $dU=T\,dS-P\,dV$, you’ve implicitly assumed that $\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}$ is zero, which isn’t the case for this material.

Comment: @Chemomechanics $\frac{\partial}{\partial T} \left(T\frac{\partial p}{\partial T} -p \right)  = \frac{\partial T}{\partial T} \frac{\partial p}{\partial T} + T\frac{\partial ^2 p}{\partial T^2}-\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}=T\frac{\partial ^2 p}{\partial T^2}$; also $T$ and $V$ are independent variables hence $\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}=\frac{nR}{V-nb}$

Comment: I agree that $\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}$ is not zero for this material. You wrote $dU=c_VdT-P\,dV$ in your answer (second equation). Since we can always write $dU=c_VdT+\left(T\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}-P\right)dV$, you’ve implicitly assumed $\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}=0$ there, yes?

Comment: @Chemomechanics write $S=S(T,V)$ and $dU=T(\partial S/\partial T dT+\partial S/\partial V dV)-pdV = T\partial S/\partial T dT + (T\partial S/\partial V -p)$ and remember Maxwell $\partial S/\partial V = \partial p/\partial T$ and and let $C_v =T \partial S/\partial T$

Comment: Yes. And yet you drop the $\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}$ term (or  $\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}$ term) in the  second equation of your answer. Why?

Comment: @Chemomechanics  because $\partial T/\partial T=1$ therefore $(\partial T/\partial T)( \partial p/\partial T) = \partial p/ \partial T$

Comment: It seems that we're talking past one another. Let's try this approach: start  with the general equation $dU=c_VdT+\left(T\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}-P\right)dV$. Insert the equation of state $P=\frac{nRT}{V-nb}-\frac{an^2}{V^2}$ and its derivative $\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}=\frac{nR}{V-nb}$. We obtain $dU=c_VdT+\frac{an^2}{V^2}dV$. This differs from the second equation in your answer.

Comment: @Chemomechanics see addendum above

Comment: @Chemomechanics thanks for pointing out the missing term in (**); I have fixed the it, see the footnote too.