# Entropy change for a real gas via Peng-Robinsons EOS

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, entropy, physical-chemistry, gas

Consider a process with inlet conditions ~300K,~50Bar and outlet conditions ~350K,~150Bar. Entropy departures as per Peng-Robinsons EOS. I am evaluating the entropy change via the following:

∆ = @ + (@. ∗ (/)) − .∗(/) − @

This gives phenomenal results for my intended application.

However, I'm concerned as technically I must use the natural logarithm. However, the natural logarithm is giving rather poor results.

Does anyone have any suggestions or alternative methods I could pursue to evaluate entropy change? Any readings throughout the literature? I highly appreciate any thoughts or suggestions.

Comment: This is $\Delta S$ per mole.  Are you using the molar Cv?  You should be using natural logarithms.  How did you get the entropy departures?  The signs on your entropy departures seem wrong?

Comment: I take back what I said about the signs of the entropy departures.

Comment: Yes using Cv kJ/kg.mol.K.

Comment: The entropy departure at inlet is -4 kJ/K, and at outlet -6kJ/K

Comment: This notation is hard to read, remember that you can edit your question. Here is a guide on how to write math in SE: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my judgment, $\Delta S$ cannot be determined for PR without first solving for the initial and final volumes, $V_1$ and $V_2$.  Then one can use the equation $dS=\frac{C_V}{T}dT+\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_VdV$ in conjunction with Hess's law to obtain:$$\Delta S=\int_{V_1}^{\infty}{F(T_1,V)dV}+C_V^{IG}\ln{(T_2/T_1)}+R\ln{(V_2/V_1)}-\int_{V_2}^{\infty}{F(T_2,V)dV}$$where $C_v^{IG}$ is the heat capacity in the ideal gas limit (infinitely large specific volume) and $$F(T,V)=\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V-\frac{R}{V}$$
For Peng-Robinson, $$F(T,V)=\frac{R}{V-b}-\frac{R}{V}+\frac{a\kappa}{b}\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{8TT_c}}\left[\frac{1}{V+b(1-\sqrt{2})}-\frac{1}{V+b(1+\sqrt{2})}\right]$$where $$\alpha(T)=\left(1+\kappa\left(1-\sqrt{\frac{T}{T_c}}\right)\right)^2$$and $$\kappa=0.37464+1.54226\omega-0.26992\omega^2$$So the entropy departure is $$S_{dep}=R\ln{\frac{V}{V-b}}+\frac{a\kappa}{b}\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{8TT_c}}\ln{\left[\frac{V+b(1+\sqrt{2})}{V+b(1-\sqrt{2})}\right]}$$

Comment: Thank you. I have solved for the volumes already. Is F(T,V) the entropy departure? I will read up on Hess's law

Comment: No, it is the argument for the integral of entropy departure.

Comment: In the previous comment, I meant that F(T,V) is the integrand  of the entropy departure integral.

Comment: What gas is this?

Comment: See the added results for Peng Robinson in my Answer

Comment: Thank you so much !! I am getting very good results now - matching what HYSYS is telling me very closely. 

This is for natural gas for compression on an offshore oil rig.

Any chance you know how I can solve this using the BWRS EOS? Peng-Robinsons was straight forward given the relative simplicity. I have access to ASPEN HYSYS but cannot find the entropy departure anywhere. Any other software tools you might be aware of? 

Thanks in advance, I'd shout you a beer if I could ! Cheers

Comment: Can I approximate ∫(T,V)dV by dropping the pressure to 0kPA at constant temperature? I plan to use HYSYS to generate the entropy values for BWRS EOS

Comment: Since entropy is a state function, we can use Hess's Law to follow any convenient path from the initial state to the final state.  In the development I employed, I used the following path:  $(T1,V1)--->(T1,V^*)$, $(T1,V^*)--->(T2,V^*)$, $(T2,V^*)--->(T2,V2)$, where V* is a very large specific volume at which the gas exhibits ideal gas behavior.  For an EOS like Peng-Robinson, where the equation is non-linear in V and linear in P, it is more convenient to work in terms of molar volume than in terms of pressure in doing the entropy departure integrations.

Comment: BWRS is another one where it is easier to integrate in terms of molar volume (which I think can be done analytically in that case as well).

Comment: Actually, getting the entropy departure for the BWRS equation is very simple.  You take partial of P with respect to T, subtract $\rho R$, divide by $\rho^2$, and integrate analytically between $\rho=0$ and arbitrary $\rho.$.

Comment: Thank you my friend. I have already built PR-EOS into Python and Excel. Due to current time constraints, I cannot afford to do the same for BWRS-EOS, although I would love to as a future project.

Do you know of any software, or python code, which can calculate the BWRS-EOS entropy departure? I have tried using Aspen Plus however the values do not seem correct and I'd like to cross check against another reference.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Like I said, it is easy to get the BWRS entropy departure analytically using the recipe I gave in my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you Chett. Really appreciate the feedback. I've since build BWRS successfully into Python and now require the calculation for entropy departure.

Here's my attempt at the mathematics:
https://imgur.com/a/BrknN0N

And in Python:
https://imgur.com/a/lF3gq4A

Unfortunately this produces incorrect results. If you can see any obvious mistakes or errors, please do let me know. Thank you so much

Comment: Actually, applying equation 10 from the report below yields very similar results. Thanks again.

 REPORT ORO-5249-2 DEVELOPMENT OF WORKING FLUID
THERMODYNAMIC PROPERTIES
INFORMATION FOR
GEOTHERMAL CYCLES - PHASE I https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/5557148

Answer (score 0):

Here you find a [derivation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/743080/entropy-of-van-der-waals-fluid/743087#743087) of the entropy change for a fluid whose EoS can be written as $p=f(V)T+g(V)$, where is derived that $$\Delta S = S-S_0=\int_{T_0}^T \frac{C_v(T)}{T}dT + \int_{V_0}^V f(V)dV$$

For the [Peng-Robinson](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/png520/m11_p2.html) model $f(V)=\frac{\alpha a}{V^2+2bV-b^2}$.

If $C_v$ is assumed to be essentially temperature independent then the first integral is $C_v\text{ln}\frac{T}{T_0}$, so in your equation the first should be a natural logarithm.

Regarding the 2nd integral you have to apply this indefinite integral:
$$\int \frac{1}{t^2+2bt-b^2} dt = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt {2}b}\text{ln}\frac{t-b_2}{t-b_1}$$ where $b_{1,2}=-b\pm 2\sqrt {2}b$ are the roots of the denominator, and substitute your known parameters in the result to be applied between fixed $V$ and $V_0$ limits for the definite integral.

Comment: In the Peng-Robinson, $\alpha$ is a function of T.

Comment: Also, Cv is a function of V.

Comment: @ChetMiller given the rather undefined nature of the problem, I took the liberty and *assumed* that $\alpha$ is constant over the temperature range of interest $300K$ and $350K$, and then  $C_v =C_v(T)$ at least per the derivation in https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/743080/entropy-of-van-der-waals-fluid/743087#743087

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to avoid numerical integration so am simply taking the mean value for parameters such as Cv.

Comment: Assuming that $\alpha$ is a constant, if you use the integral I gave above then you do not need any numerical integration just substituting your parameters $V, V_0$ in the log function.

Comment: Thank you. I will try today and report back. I really appreciate the feedback. 
Quickly - Is Cv the actual Cv for the real gas, or Cv for ideal gas. Thank you in advance

Comment: $C_v$ is for the gas satisfying the Peng-Robinson EoS. It is the one that describes the caloric state of the gas and is not determined by the EoS itself. If $\alpha$ depends on $T$ nonlinearly then the gas cannot be "ideal" because $C_v$ will also depend on $V$ explicitly. Given the gas you may have to look it up in tables or ask @ChetMiller what a good practical value for $C_v$ is if the other parameters are given. (and you should recheck my integral formula, too, I think it is right but you can never know...)

Comment: In the equation I gave, all you need to know is Cv in the ideal gas limit where Cv is a known function only of temperature (and not V).  The ideal gas Cv is known from the literature for most gases of interest.