# Partial derivatives and the Joule Coefficient

Tags: thermodynamics, calculus, differentiation

The Joule Coefficient for a van der Waals gas can be shown to be
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_U=-\frac{a}{C_VV^2}
\end{equation}
where $U$ is the internal energy of the gas, $V$ is the volume, $T$ is the temperature, $a$ is a constant (a parameter in the vdw equation of state) and $C_V$ is the heat capacity at constant volume.

I want to evaluate the derivative of $C_V$ with respect to $V$ at constant $T$.  The "correct" way to do it is the following:
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\partial C_V}{\partial V}\right)_T=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial V}\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V\right)_T=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial T}\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T\right)_V=\;...\;=0
\end{align}
I'm happy with this method (I know how to get $\left({\partial U}/{\partial V}\right)_T$ using the master equation and a relevant Maxwell relation etc.)

However when I try to do it another way using the Joule coefficient relation to $C_V$ at the beginning, I can't get the correct answer:
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\partial C_V}{\partial V}\right)_T=-\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial V}\frac{a}{V^2}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_U\right)_T=\frac{2a}{V^3}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_U-\frac{a}{V^2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial V}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_U\right)_T
\end{align}
In the second term, I want to swap the $\partial V$ and $\partial T$ around, but then it seems I'll have a $\left({\partial V}/{\partial V}\right)_T=1$ term, which then vanishes when doing $\partial/\partial T$ on it.  The first term is not zero, so this method is clearly wrong.  Is there some rule about partial differentiation I'm forgetting that disallows this?

Comment: I didn't elaborate because that's not the important part of my question, but yeah it's not zero, it's $$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T=T\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_V-p$$, which for vdw is not temperature dependent, so the $\partial/\partial T$ derivative vanishes.

Comment: Your error is that you have interchanged the order of differentiation with respect to $V$ and $T$ in a function that depends on $V$ and $T$  explicitly but keeping $U$ constant not $T$. In fact, keeping $U(T,V)$ does not mean that you keep $T$ constant that would be the requirement for the commutativity.

Comment: This is subtle to me, but yes I think this makes sense.  Is it possible to generalise this and say $$\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial D}\left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial B}\right)_C\right)_E=\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial B}\left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial D}\right)_E\right)_C$$ only if $B$ and $E$ are the same variables, and $C$ and $D$ are the same variables?

Comment: Good question but I do not know if and when that is true.  Maybe you should ask it as a separate question.

Comment: I disagree with @Chemomechanics and I agree with you that for a van der Waals gas $C_v=C_v(T)$ and is independent of $V$. Using the same formula as you have I showed this for the general case $p=f(V)T+g(V)$ [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/743080/entropy-of-van-der-waals-fluid/743087#743087), unfortunately it is full of typos...