# Enthalpy of a Van der Waals gas

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy, gas

I was thinking about how would one find the enthalpy in terms of $V,T$ but not on the usual ideal gas, but instead on a Van Der Waals gas with *constant temperature*, that is, a gas that satisfies: $$(P+\frac{an^2}{V^2})(V-nb)=nRT$$ with $a,b$ constants. We all know that the enthalpy is defined as $$H=U+PV\Rightarrow dH=dU+VdP+PdV$$ and since we are taking constant temperature (isothermic) to make our lifes easier, and $dU=TdS-PdV$ we get $$dH=dU+PdV+VdP=TdS+VdP$$ since and by definition of the entropy in terms of pressure and temperature $dS=C_p \frac{dT}{T}+\frac{nR}{P}dP=\frac{nR}{P}dP$ (since temperature is constant) we can get $$dH=T(\frac{nR}{P}dP)+VdP=(\frac{nRT}{P}+V)dP$$ but am I supposed to substitute one of the variables $n,V,T$ with the Van Der Waals? On any case I could get a very long expression and I don't think it is possible, how can I enhance this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entropy of Van der Waals fluid](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/743080/entropy-of-van-der-waals-fluid)

Comment: @march I meant enthalpy, my bad. You can see it in the body of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation for dS is for an ideal gas.  For a real gas, it reads:  $$dS=\frac{C_P}{T}dT-\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_PdP$$

Comment: Oh, that's true. So for my case, since I am considering $T=constant$, doesn't the entropy simplify to $dS=-(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T})_P dP$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Expand the enthalpy in $T$ and $V$:

$$\begin{align}\require{cancel}dH&=\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_V\cancelto{0}{dT}+\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial V}\right)_TdV\\&=\left[T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T+V\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_T\right]dV\\&=\left[T\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V-K\right]dV\\&=\left[-T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_T-K\right]dV\\&=\left(\alpha T K-K\right)dV\\&=K(\alpha T-1)\,dV,\end{align}$$

where $K$ is the [isothermal bulk modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus) and $\alpha$ is the [constant-pressure thermal expansion coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_expansion) and where a [Maxwell relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_relations) and the [triple product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule) were applied. This relation holds for all closed systems at constant temperature. (For the ideal gas, for which $\alpha=1/T$, it is identically zero.)