# Enthalpy of a Van der Waals gas continuation

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, entropy, gas, volume

In my previous question [Enthalpy of a Van der Waals gas](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/787732/375178), I got the expression of the enthalpy generalised, but I am still having issues finishing it since it might have some quite hard calculus...

For my Van der Waals gas with constant temperature we got to the following expression by the already mentioned question: $$dH=TdS+VdP=T(-\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}dP)+VdP=(V-\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}T)dP$$ while the Van der Waals equation is $$(P+\frac{an^2}{V^2})(V-nb)=P(V-nb)+\frac{an^2}{V}-\frac{an^3 b}{V^2}=nRT$$ and solving for $P$ to get the $\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}$ we get $$P=\frac{nRT-\frac{an^2 V-an^3 b}{V^2}}{V-nb}=\frac{nRTV^2-an^3 V-an^3 b}{(V-nb)V^2}$$ and so we can find the partial derivative term $$\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}=\frac{(2nRTV-ab^3)(V^2 (V-nb))-(nRTV^2-an^3 V-an^3 b)(3V^2-2nbV)}{(V^3-nbV^2)^2}$$ which seems already extremely large, am I on the right path or is there an easier way?

Comment: It would be a good idea to indicate explicitly which variables are constant in every partial derivative.

Comment: One way that is for sure easier is to find the internal energy U and then enthalpy is just H = U + PV

Comment: @ErJio how would that be done though? I'm looking for $\Delta H$ not $H$, and I wouldn't know how to find the $\Delta U$

Comment: @Ulshy $\Delta H$ for a certain process? In that case you just find $H$ and calculate $\Delta H  = H(\text{initial state}) - H(\text{final state})$. To find $U$ in the first place you start at $\mathrm dU = T\mathrm dS - P\mathrm dV$ and expand $\mathrm dS$ to get $\mathrm dU = T(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\mathrm dT + \frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\mathrm dV)  - P\mathrm dV$. The temperature term is just $C_V\mathrm dT$ while one of the Maxwell relations tells you $\frac{\partial S}{\partial V} = \frac{\partial P}{\partial T}$ which cancels nicely with $-P$.

Comment: @ErJio how does it cancel? It should be $dU=C_v dT+(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}T-P)dV$, I don't see where it cancels

Comment: @Ulshy Yeah that probably wasn't the best way to state it, but what I meant was that if you expand out $(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}T - P)$ part of it cancels so you get a single term easy to integrate

Comment: @ErJio so you suggest to actually calculate the partial derivative of P wrt T and simplify that monster expression? Or else I don't know how anything else is going to simplify nor how do I get a easy term to integrate

Comment: @Ulshy $P = \frac{nRT}{V-bn} - \frac{an^2}{V^2}$ so $\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}T - P = (\frac{nR}{V-bn})T - (\frac{nRT}{V-bn} - \frac{an^2}{V^2}) = \frac{an^2}{V^2}$ which is easy to integrate

Comment: @ErJio sorry to keep insisting but how does my big expression of $\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}$ wrote in my post simplify to that? And also my expression for P in my post is quite more complicated than yours?

Comment: @Ulshy No worries. First, we both have the same expression for $P$ however you combined it into a single term. You can derive my form from $(P+\frac{an^2}{V^2})(V-bn) = nRT$ by dividing both sides by $(V-bn)$ then subtracting both sides by $\frac{an^2}{V^2}$. Second, your expression for $\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}$ will not simplify into $\frac{an^2}{V^2}$. Since you've expressed $\mathrm dH$ in terms of $\mathrm dP$ you have to integrate by $P$ which involves expressing $V$ as a function of $P$ (not easy). This is why I suggested using internal energy, since it involves simple expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is wrong.  It should read $$dH=\left(V-T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P\right)dP$$
You may have to integrate this numerically because of the non-linearity with of the VDW equation with respect to V.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by integrating it numerically? Also what do you mean by non-linearity? I'm surprised this is this difficult since it should be fairly approacheable (my prof said it)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the initial and final states of the gas, it is easier to get the enthalpy change for a VDW gas by working with the internal energy change $\Delta U$ than $\Delta H$.  This is because the internal energy change for a VDW gas can be expressed analytically:  $$\Delta U=nC_v\Delta T+nR\ln{\left(\frac{V_2-nb}{V_1-nb}\right)}$$For a VDW gas, Cv is independent of V. From the definition of $\Delta H$, $$\Delta H=\Delta U+\Delta (PV)$$

Comment: Sorry for responding late, I didn't see this. The internal energy seems different from the one in my book but on any case I don't know how to express $\Delta(PV)=\Delta P V+\Delta V P$, I'm guessing I can write $P=P(V)$ in terms of the volume and integrate and likewise with $V=V(P)$, or else I don't know how

Comment: You presumably know the initial pressures and volumes, right?

Comment: What is given in the problem statement?

Comment: The initial and final volume, temperature, $a$ and $b$, and the mass, so yeah we can find the initial and final pressure with the Van der Waals equation, isn't it?

Comment: The thing is I don't know how to find $V\Delta P$, since with $P\Delta V$ I can integrate $P\Delta V=\int_{V_0}^{V_f} PdV=\int_{V_0}^{V_f}(\frac{nRT}{V-bn}-\frac{an^2}{V^2})dV$ easily but it is hard to find an expression for $V$ in terms of $P$ with the Van der Waals equations, since you get a cubic polynomial

Comment: $\Delta (PV)=P_2V_2-P_1V_1$, and you know all four of these.